# How is the prompt to add site as an application for tel links triggered?

Tags: javascript, url-scheme

A customer sent me a link to check something in an online switchboard. After logging in with Firefox I saw this prompt:

[image: Prompt to add site as an application for tel links]

Checking the source I could not find how this is triggered. How is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Navigator.registerProtocolHandler`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler) does registration. And browser asks user for confirmation then.

Beware not all the browsers support this, so check for method's existence